# Eclipse product configuration: Setting launcherArgs for "arch"

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, p2, tycho

The eclipse product configuration has the section "launcherArgs" which can be specified globally or for any supported platform. We build our product for `win32` as `x86` and `x86_64` and I want to have a different .ini generated depending on the arch property. To be specific: It´s an in-house application and the JVMs are rolled out to the same directory on every client, but differs between 32bit and 64bit machines.

We build with maven/tycho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be achieved in the p2.inf advice file using these keywords:

`filter=(&(osgi.os=win32)(osgi.arch=x86_64)) instructions.configure=setProgramProperty(propName:-vm,propValue:64bitVM)`

It´s actually not that easy and the correct syntax of the p2.inf file remains a miracle to me. But somehow I got this working. A look to the content.xml file can be helpful if anyone also want´s to do stuff in the p2.inf file...

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this is a limitation/bug of the PDE product file format which tycho re-uses.

Comment: I´m currently investigating the p2 touchpoints - do you think there is a possibility to set the `-vm` parameter in the .ini file according to the value of the `arch` property?

Comment: I guess it should using something like this in the p2.inf:
`filter=(&(osgi.os=win32)(osgi.arch=x86_64))
instructions.configure=setProgramProperty(propName:-vm,propValue:64bitVM)`
Will try that later...